# 3D Painting: mirror on the z axis uncentered

Tags: texture-painting

[image]I was trying to 3d paint my object, with simmetry set to Z axis.
When painting, the paint on the other side of the object is "offsetted" a bit higher or lower, depending on where I am painting, hence I can't paint correcly.
I verified the object is perfectly aligned with the three axes, and I tried to set the origin to the part I am painting, but nothing. I have also tried both ortographic and non ortographic viewpoints.

Comment: Just a question for clarification: you've set the symmetry to Z axis? What I see in the screenshot is a right side view and a left side view of a beak. So I would guess you need X axis symmetry (or maybe Y axis symmetry).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the image is purely for showing the effect.

Comment: So is this supposed to be symmetrical on the X axis while you are trying to work with Z axis symmetry? Are your UVs laid out correctly? Is the geometry symmetrical?

Comment: The Object from tail to beak is aligned with Y axis. From left to right wing is aligned witx X Axis, and from the ground up to the head is aligned with Z axis. Precisely, Left wing is on the X+ verse, the right wing is on the X- verse, the tail ins on Y+ verse and the beak is on the Y- verse. But also selecting X mirroring,  i obtain totally offsetted/wrong results. I can't figure what is happening

Comment: Well, maybe you should upload the file because simply looking at the screenshot doesn't really show what might be wrong with the symmetry. I understand that everything might be **aligned** with the axes, but I was asking if the mesh is completely **symmetrical** on those axes. Especially I'm wondering when you originally tried to paint symmetrical on the Z axis this would mean your bird looks the same no matter if it's standing on his feet or you flip it top down...

Comment: What happens when applying rotation and scale first?